# Let $u \in C^2 (\Omega) \cap C (\bar \Omega) $ be a solution: $\Delta u = f(u)$ in $\Omega$ and $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$. Show that $u \equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: x^2 + y^2<1 \}$ and assume that $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a strictly increasing function with $f(0) =0$. Let $u \in C^2 (\Omega) \cap C (\bar \Omega) $ be a solution of the following problem: $$\Delta u = f(u)$$ in $\Omega$ and $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$. Show that $u \equiv 0$.
I have two ideas. The first is to multiply $u$ on the equation first and then integrate, which gives us $\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 = -\int_{\Omega} uf(u)$,but don't know how to use the condition of $f$. The second one is just integrate the equation which gives us $\int_{\Omega} f(u) = \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}dS$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you show that $uf(u)\ge 0$, then $0\le\int|\nabla u|^2\le 0$, so $\nabla u\equiv 0$, and your result follows.  To do this, use that $f$ is strictly increasing.  If $u>0$, then $f(u)>0$, so $uf(u)>0$.  If $u<0$, then $f(u)<0$, so $uf(u)>0$.  If $u=0$, then $uf(u)=0$.

Comment: Thanks! I was close.